# Making custom line width scale according to predefined line widths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm creating some custom shape definitions in `TikZ`, and I want certain parts of the shapes to have thicker line widths than the rest. However, I still want to be able to scale the line thickness as normal.

Consider an example where my custom shape is made up of `0.4pt` (`thin`) lines and `1.2pt` (`very thick`) lines for a figure with default (thin) line width. If I increase the line thickness of the figure from `thin` to `very thick`, the shape should have line widths of `1.2pt` and `3.6pt`.

How can I achieve this? Wild attempts like `[line width=+0.8pt]` did nothing.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\mic(#1)(#2)(#3);{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate={#2},scale={#3}]
        \draw (0,0) circle (0.22);
        \draw % this is where I need help
            (-0.22,-0.3) -- (-0.22,0.3);
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % [line width=thick] for instance
    \mic(0,0)(0)(1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
\tikzset{
 thicker/.style={line width=#1\pgflinewidth},
 thicker/.default={2},
}


\def\mic(#1)(#2)(#3);{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate={#2},scale={#3}]
        \draw (0,0) circle (0.22);
        \draw[thicker=1.5] % this is where I need help
            (-0.22,-0.3) -- (-0.22,0.3);
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{tikzpicture} % [line width=thick] for instance
    \mic(0,0)(0)(1);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=1cm, very thick]
      \mic(0,0)(0)(1);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

The style `[thicker]` multiplies the current line width by the factor you specify (2 by default).

Comment: I tried modifying the expression to add a constant to the line width instead. However, when I write `thicker/.style={line width=\pgflinewidth+#1}, thicker/.default={0.3pt}`. The value of `#1` is doubled. With the default value in the example, the line width will be 0.6pt thicker, not 0.3pt. Any idea why?